# What is the "bilinear interpolation kernel" in personlab paper?

Tags: image-processing, interpolation

What is this bilinear interpolation kernel in the paper [PersonLab: Person Pose Estimation and Instance Segmentation with a Bottom-Up, Part-Based, Geometric Embedding Model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08225) page 6 equation (1)?

Here it is:
$$
h_k(x) = \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\sum_{i=1:N}p_k(x_i)B(x_i+S_k(x_i)-x)
$$
where:

- $x$, $x_i$ are image coordinates (2-D vectors).
- $h_k \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ localized heatmaps obtained by a sort of Hough voting.
- $S_k \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ offest vectors
- $p_k \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ heatmaps
- $B(.)$ *denotes the bilinear interpolation kernel.*

> This is a
> form of Hough voting: each point i in the image crop grid
> casts a vote with its estimate for the position of every keypoint, with the vote being weighted by the probability that
> it is in the disk of influence of the corresponding keypoint

I guess bilinear interpolation kernel is a class of function and not an actual one (I may be wrong).

But if it is bilinear why does it only take one argument in the equation?

Maybe this is bilinear 1D interpolation, interpolating between the coordinates of 2-D vector?

Otherwise this formula doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/kXn8GJxS/Bilinear-interpolation-kernel.png

Comment: Can I have a little more details?
This does not help me understanding the formula in the paper, nor why the bilinear interpolation kernel only have one parameter in the formula despite being called bilinear.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276034240_Linear_Methods_for_Image_Interpolation/download

Answer (score 1):

When I read «bilinear interpolation kernel» in image processing, I assume that they mean bilinear image imterpolation:
y(n+t) = (t-1)*x(n) + t*x(n+1)

If you decide upon a fixed uniform upsampling factor and standard dsp «zero-fill then lowpass filter» upsampling, the convolution kernel turns out to be samples of a triangular waveform.

-k

Comment: I've added more details about the equation members to make more sense of it.